# Are queues CTMC?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, queueing-theory

The $M/M/1$ queue have all the properties of the countable state continuous time markov chain.

Is any general queue also a countable state CTMC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$M/M/1$ and its relatives are the queues which are markov chains.

This is since these queues have exponentially distributed interarrival times and service times.

$M/D/1$ is not a markov chain but there exists an imbedded discrete time markov chain whose properties provide information about the process.

$M/G/1, G/G/1$ etc are not markov chains.

But if either the interarrival times or service times are exponentially distributed then the general theory of markov chains still provides a method for studying the queue.